# Trading price of 2 consumers with the same utility function

Tags: economics

Say that two consumers, A and B, have the same utility function, just $u(x) = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2$ for simplicity. If consumer A has endowment $x_A = (4, 3)$, and consumer B has endowment $x_B = (3, 4)$, and the price of good 2 is $p_2 = 1$. I think they would definitely gain if they trade with each other, but what's a price $p_1$ where they will be willing to trade? If the consumers traded a marginal amount at that price, who will give up $x_1$ to receive $x_2$?

Comment: Have a look [at this pdf](http://paolocrosetto.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/pset6_solutions_handout.pdf) for a complete solution.

Comment: That seems like a weird utility function. Anyway, it would seem optimal for the two consumers to trade in a way such that consumer A will end up with endowment $(7,0)$ and comsumer B with endowment $(0,7)$. It is unclear to me what "price" means here and how that figure enters the problem.